# Prevent navigation defined in the <Link/> element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a component in React/NextJS like this:

```
import Link from 'next/link';

 <Link className={styles.slidercontentbottom} href="/projects" onClick={(event)=> console.log(event.target)}> 
                <button onClick={goToPreviousSlide}
                  className={styles.sliderbtnleft}>
                    <AiOutlineArrowLeft/>
                </button>
                <div className={styles.sliderfeature}>
                  <h1 className={styles.featuretitle}>Some text</h1>
                  <p className={styles.featuretext}></p>
                </div>
                <button onClick={goToNextSlide} className={styles.sliderbtnright}><AiOutlineArrowRight/>
                </button>
              </Link>
```

which looks like this:
[image]

So it's a page with a slider background, where you can slide images. When I click anywhere on the screen it goes to **/projects**, which is my intention **EXCEPT** with the button left and right. When I click on them it slides the image and then immediately goes to /projects. Is there a way to prevent the navigation to /projects after clicking the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is!

If you look at your code, you'll notice the entire code block is wrapped in a `<Link>`

To do what you need to, just put the link deeper into your component tree to just wrap the background, and not the buttons like this:

```
<>
<button onClick={goToPreviousSlide} className={styles.sliderbtnleft}>
    <AiOutlineArrowLeft />
</button>
<Link
    className={styles.slidercontentbottom}
    href='/projects'
    onClick={(event) => console.log(event.target)}
>
    <div className={styles.sliderfeature}>
        <h1 className={styles.featuretitle}>Some text</h1>
        <p className={styles.featuretext}></p>
    </div>
</Link>
<button onClick={goToNextSlide} className={styles.sliderbtnright}>
    <AiOutlineArrowRight />
</button>
</>
```

You may also notice we replaced the `Link` component with `<>`, which is a shorthand for an [empty React Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html). This is because a React component must only have one top-level element.

Comment: This is just the simplified version of my component. My whole component is wrapped in a div. But your option does not answer my question. If I put it deeper into my component, it breaks my design.

Comment: You'll find this is the best way. If your design is affected, it may be that you'll need to move around some CSS class names. I leave this as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Maybe it breaks your design because of the way `styles.sliderContentBottom` is defined. If you need styles on the container, replace the react fragment tags (`<></>`) with a div tag and assign it the corresponding style. I think this is a correct answer because it provides a better structure and solves the stated problem. A button being a child of a Link does sound problematic in the sense you'll have two listeners on the click of the button (the reason why you get both the slide and the redirect I think).